# Запись звука с микрофона

Tags: библиотеки, аудио, звукозапись, c++

Нужно постоянно проверять, говорит ли человек в микрофон или нет. Если говорит, то записывать это в файл, как только он прекратил говорить - прекращать записывать.
Какую библиотеку нужно использовать для проверки и записи с микрофона на с++?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от операционной системы. Говорите конкретнее - хочу писать под такую-то операционную систему в такой-то среде. Посмотрите еще [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034096/linux-c-audio-capturing-just-microphone-library)

Comment: Windows, Visual c++ 2010

Comment: Ну, например, тогда [так][1] или [так][2]

 [1]:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library
 [2]:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31541/Audio-Capture-with-DirectShow-Part-1